# iOS 3+ programming a uiprogressview w/o a nib (I have theos)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiprogressview, cydia, theos

I have implemented FlowCover programmatically.  On the click of an image in the cover flow, I would like a uiprogressview bar to appear below the image in the cover flow.

Here is my current code snippet for the area of concern:

```
 - (void) flowCover:(FlowCoverView *)view didSelect:(int)deb {
     NSLog(@"Downloading Track %d ...", deb);
    switch (deb % 6) {
                case 0:
                default:
    system("wget -O /some/Local/File/Name.blah http://urlBeingDownloadedFrom.com/aFile.blah");
                case 1:.....
    NSLog(@"Track %d Downloaded!", deb);
        }
    }
```

I would also like the `UIProgressView` to disappear when complete and alert the user when it is fully downloaded, and if the file size is less than expected, alert the user of that.  I know how to make alerts, so no need to tell me how a `UIAlertView` is shown (just show "// Alert goes here."). I am using theos for iOS; I am not using Xcode. I am using the iOS 3 SDK, as I want to support a lot of users.  This is for Cydia, not the App Store.

EDIT: OK, I can make a uiprogressview work with NSURLConnection and I also have 4 other download stats.  Now what I am wondering is how to change the uilabel with the song name to match the album cover currently shown.  I know I can do:
    label.text = @"SongNameHere";
But I want to change it per change of cover.

Comment: You don't have to use the iOS 3 SDK to run a binary on iOS 3 devices.  In fact you will have the opposite problem, newer devices (the vast majority of devices) might have problems running it.

Comment: So far, my apps are still compatible, but thanks anyway.  I find that weird that old isn't supported on new.

Comment: Why?  That's totally normal.  Things change, things get deprecated.  It's like writing a piece of software for Windows 98 and expecting it to execute as-is on Windows 8.

Comment: HAH, nice comparison there.

Comment: The max iOS I have is 4.2.1 (iPod 2G).

Comment: Anyway, do you have a solution for the question?

Comment: I made changes in the question.

Comment: Do I understand you want a `UIProgressView` whilst you shell out to `wget` using `system`?  Not likely since you'll have blocked the UI thread.  You ought to consider asynchronous operations, or failing that, using a thread to do your downloading, with synchronisation to the UI thread.

Comment: Nope, no need for wget, since I can use nsurlconnection instead.  I got uiprogressview linked with nsurlconnection.

Comment: Can you even compile for armv6 any more?

Comment: According to Apple, as of June less than 1% of downloads from the app store were iOS less than 5, how many of those do you think were iOS 3? iOS 4 has been out over 3 years, and the only devices limited to iOS 3 are iPhone and iPod GEN 1. NO ONE IS USING THEM. I try to support as far back as reasonable and I have dropped 4 now. By supporting 3, you'll be locking yourself out of so many features that you'll make the experience worse for your users with higher devices, i.e. every single one of them.

Comment: Yes, I can compile for armv6, and I do not have a Mac.

Comment: And that stat is because almost 100% of all apps in the app store only support iOS 4.3 and up.  When I can code for iOS 4-7, I will but I will still make OS-specific binaries and run the correct one with a runtime script.  For now, my apps will be for Cydia, so I don't care about stats from apple.